# io_stall question

Tags: sql-server-2012, performance

I just installed SQL Server on new hardware and ran a test script to show io_stall information by file.  Nothing else has been loaded yet, just a fresh install of SQL Server 2012.  Why are the io_stalls for reads and writes high?  See output below.  We are using separate SSD drives for data, logs, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I really don't think you have anything to worry about here. Unless you mean a completely separate SSD + controller for every individual file, there are always going to be competes for concurrent read/write activity. Even then I suspect the OS can't write to 20 different files at the same time without any of them waiting on each other to some minor degree.

As a reference, I ran [the same script you did](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dpless/leveraging-sys-dm_io_virtual_file_stats) on my lowly local VM, which has a single disk, and here is what I see ([click to enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47Yzu.png)):

> [image]

Worry about it when I/O is actually a symptomatic problem based on other observations as well, not just because your `io_stall` number is non-zero.